# Untrack git file

Tags: git, symfony, gitignore

Here is the think, I have a database field with some html.

```
<span class="orange"><a href="/pdf/MY_PDF.pdf">Title</a></span>
```

Last day, my boss told me he wanted to change this pdf. So, i thought I just had to put the new file in the folder and change his name inside the database (MY_PDF2.pdf) for example.

But this is tricky because the file is tracked by git... so to see the new pdf I had to commit just this single PDF. The thing is it's a customer file... so if we have to make some commit each time they want to change... this is crazy.

So I just want to say to git that the file doesn't need to be tracked.

It's under Symfony and this is my file location : C/wamp/www/sitename/web/pdf/

So I would like my git don't tracked the pdf folder anymore.
But I don't know how to do that... sure I can put it into my gitignore... but all the others dev will still have the old one...cause I think gitignore is ignored as well...

Not sure I'm very clear, sorry. Don't hesitate to ask what you don't understand in my question.  Thanks

Comment: If you *really* want to make it an untracked file, you *must* remove it from the index. Using `git update-index --assume-unchanged` means that the saved index version goes into every future commit: Git just stops *telling* you about the file. However, removing it has its own issues: specifically, that this causes the file to get removed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can add a file/folder or a pattern to `.gitignore` file, and git would never track it.

```
echo "*.pdf" >> .gitignore # run this command from your project main directory
```

Otherwise just add `*.pyc` in the `.gitignore` file yourself.

If your file is already tracked then you need to run this command too.

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

If your file disappeared and you don't know what to do - you need to

```
run command git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>
```

Comment: I did that but, when i'm going to push my gitignore, i think the other dev won't be able to get it back.  I might just be wrong.

Comment: Won't be able to get what back?

Comment: The gitignore file.

Comment: gitignore file should be tracked, and when other developer pulls the changes his gitignore file will be updated as well. Forgive me, but I'm unable to see the issue.

Comment: Ok, I was just thinking it didn't so there is no more problem. Thanks.

Comment: if your file disappeared and you don't know what to do - you need to run command `git update-index --no-assume-unchanged <file>`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stop tracking the files, but not delete it from your system:

Add the folder in your `.gitignore`.

Run this code to keep the files locally and remove the files from your repository.

`git rm -r --cached .`

Then:

`git add .`

And commit:

`git commit -m "Remove PDF files"`

Answer (score 0):

To work with exact file:

1. Add relative path into .gitignore.
2. 

```
git rm --cached <relative path>
git add <relative path>
```

3. do commit